# Pandas: groupby and make a new column applying aggregate to two columns

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, aggregate

I'm having a difficulty with applying `agg` to a `groupby` pandas dataframe.

I have a dataframe `df` like this:

```
order_id    distance_theo    bird_distance 
      10              100               80
      10               80               80
      10               70               80
      11               90               70
      11               70               70
      11               60               70
      12              200              180
      12              150              180
      12              100              180
      12               60              180
```

I want to groupby `order_id`, and make a new column `crow` by dividing `distance_theo` of the first row in each group by `bird_distance` in the first row of each group(or in any row, because there is only one value of `bird_distance` in one group).

```
order_id    distance_theo    bird_distance    crow
      10              100               80    1.25
      10               80               80    1.25
      10               70               80    1.25
      11               90               70    1.29
      11               70               70    1.29
      11               60               70    1.29
      12              200              180    1.11
      12              150              180    1.11
      12              100              180    1.11
      12               60              180    1.11
```

My attempt:
df.groupby('order_id').agg({'crow', lambda x: x.distance_theo.head(1) / x.bird_distance.head(1)})

But I get an error:

```
'Series' object has no attribute 'distance_theo'
```

How can I solve this? Thanks for any kinds of advice!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `groupby` with `first`:

```
s = df.groupby('order_id').transform('first')
df.assign(crow=s.distance_theo.div(s.bird_distance))

   order_id  distance_theo  bird_distance      crow
0        10            100             80  1.250000
1        10             80             80  1.250000
2        10             70             80  1.250000
3        11             90             70  1.285714
4        11             70             70  1.285714
5        11             60             70  1.285714
6        12            200            180  1.111111
7        12            150            180  1.111111
8        12            100            180  1.111111
9        12             60            180  1.111111
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do it without groupby and use `drop_duplicate` and `join`:

```
df.join(df.drop_duplicates('order_id')\
  .eval('crow = distance_theo / bird_distance')[['crow']]).ffill()
```

or use `assign` instead of `eval` per @jezraela comments below:

```
df1.join(df1.drop_duplicates('order_id')\
   .assign(crow=df1.distance_theo / df1.bird_distance)[['crow']]).ffill()
```

Output:

```
   order_id  distance_theo  bird_distance      crow
0        10            100             80  1.250000
1        10             80             80  1.250000
2        10             70             80  1.250000
3        11             90             70  1.285714
4        11             70             70  1.285714
5        11             60             70  1.285714
6        12            200            180  1.111111
7        12            150            180  1.111111
8        12            100            180  1.111111
9        12             60            180  1.111111
```

Comment: Dont use `eval`, there is ugly bug - working only for 100 rows :(

Comment: Oh...... I didn't know this.  Can you point me to bug report or stack overflow post showing the error?  Thank you!

Comment: Try google a bit, I once 2 hour debug it. try test for 200rows data.